# Uninstall ms teams app / bot for a user ( bot framework bot )

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is it possible to uninstall a bot for a user in ms teams using some MS graph api or any other method? We have a user which is not able to talk to a bot in teams. It used to work before, but lately every messages user types runs into an error. So we were thinking to delete / uninstall the bot for that user and, have him install again.

Answer (score 1):

There is an endpoint that you should be able to use for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-delete-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . Would it not be easier to just have the user uninstall the app in Teams though (right click on the app's icon and select 'Uninstall').

That said, I don't know if it would help - it sounds like something else might be wrong. Is this the only user having the issue? If everyone is seeing it, you should check if the Teams 'Channel' is enabled in the Bot's settings in the Azure resource (here's more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-channels?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

Comment: Yes this is only user having this issue. Also we dont see 'Uninstall' option anywhere on this bot in teams. Its 1:1 scope bot

Comment: In the left menu, with "notifications", "activity", "chat", etc. - is the app in there? It might be hidden behind the 3 dots menu "...". If it's there, right click and select Uninstall

Comment: Thanks, I found it and right click on it gave Uninstall option.

Comment: great stuff, glad to help. Please go ahead an upvote so others in future can see this answer if they have a similar issue